# How to reduce the gap between tags of the x-axis

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

Here is my problem : i can't figure out to reduce the gap between tags of the x-axis.

[image: [Picture of problem :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4QiG.png)]
Do you mind to help me ?
Thanks

I didn't find function to fix this problem. I'm using pandas for data entries : series

Comment: Hi Tom! Could you please provide more context? What are you trying to plot? Can you give some reproducable code? I think that would help, at least for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you rotate the x-axis tick labels, the centre of the label text string will be aligned with the associated tick mark. E.g., the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Fraud type": [
           "Computers",
           "Telephones, Fax machines and Two-way Radios",
           "Another very long label with a lot of words in it",
           "Yet another very long labels with even more words in it than the last one",
           "Audio Accessories", "Soft Furnishings"],
        "No. of fraud": [100, 55, 38, 16, 12, 2],
    }
)

ax = df.plot.bar(x="Fraud type", y="No. of fraud", rot=45)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

will give:

[image]

What you instead need to do is manually set the [horizontal alignment](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_horizontalalignment) of the tick labels. You could change the above example to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Fraud type": [
           "Computers",
           "Telephones, Fax machines and Two-way Radios",
           "Another very long label with a lot of words in it",
           "Yet another very long labels with even more words in it than the last one",
           "Audio Accessories", "Soft Furnishings"],
        "No. of fraud": [100, 55, 38, 16, 12, 2],
    }
)

ax = df.plot.bar(x="Fraud type", y="No. of fraud")

# manually set rotation and horizontal position of the labels
for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
   label.set_rotation(45)
   label.set_ha("right")  # align tick with the right of the label text

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]